# Lexical or Preprocesser issue: Xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I am coding a basic React Native app and am getting a lexical or preprocessor issue in Xcode. I tried pod deintegrating and pod installing, yet the error persisted. I also tried react-native run-ios instead of using Xcode, but it didn't work. Here is the error:

[image]

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'LocalMainStreet' do
  # Pods for LocalMainStreet
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

  pod 'Stripe', '~> 14.0.0'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false

  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera.podspec'
  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  target 'LocalMainStreetTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Got a space in your path? “/Users/vetc/The ???” Shouldn’t matter except when it does. Add an underscore or camel case it.